# How to retrieve the header and footer from pdf using itext in java?

Tags: java, itext

I know headers & footers are stored in a "Phrase" object. 
https://itextpdf.com/examples gives many examples to add headers & footers but not to retrieve them. 

Is there any getHeader() or getPhrase() ?

Answer (score 0):

You say that headers and footers are stored in a `Phrase` object. That allegation is incorrect. You can create headers and footers using a `Phrase` object when using iText, but other software will use other approaches.

A PDF consists of a series of objects that are interrelated. They actually for a tree if you start with the root object and then take a look at the page tree, the form entry (if any), and so on.

Each page dictionary refers to a(t least one) stream object. In that stream object, you'll find PDF syntax that strokes lines, fills shapes and shows text. Every snippet of text is added at an absolute position, and such a snippet isn't aware of phrases.

For instance: the contents of a table cell don't know they belong to a table cell. A line of text doesn't know if it's part of a paragraph, if it's a title, or... maybe a header or a footer **except if you have a tagged PDF.**

In case of a tagged PDF, you have a `StructTreeRoot` entry in the root dictionary and when you look at this structure tree, you can see the semantics of every piece of data. There will be references to *marked content* operators in the content streams which allow you to find out which parts of the content belong to which structure element, for instance a paragraph, a table cell,...
Headers and footers usually aren't part of the content. They are marked as *artifacts*.

Long story short: either your PDF is tagged, in which case you have to look for the header and footer artifacts. Or your PDF isn't tagged, in which case you'll need to write some code that *guesses* which parts of the content stream are headers and footers based on heuristics.

Comment: Is there any sample code which parses content stream? otherwords, how to access content stream?

Comment: See the examples that come with chapter 15 of my book: http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=15 (But you may want to read ISO-32000-1 first, because you don't seem to be up to speed regarding your knowledge of the Portable Document Format.)